# When the salt is applied before the text is salted , then what is "that"?

Tags: hash

In all the documentation I read that the salt is applied before the text is hashed and the salt is stored somewhere in the database in plain text.

So for example bcrypt generates the following structure:

```
$2y$10$M8z/Bcli/eh3ay5.4w4Y5.hbTZ2wrwDKdJXkCQ7HuFazAzOqZzl4`.

$2y$10$M8z/Bcli/   <-- this does not look like a part of the hash
```

What kind of structure is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are looking at [Modular Crypt Format](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/modular_crypt_format.html).

- 2y identifies a specific version of the bcrypt algorithm
- 10 specifies the number of rounds
- M8z/Bcli/eh3ay5.4w4Y5. is the salt

and the rest is the hash according to the modular crypt format [bcrypt page](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.bcrypt.html#passlib.hash.bcrypt).

It seems the Modular Crypt Format is "deprecated" in favor of [PHC-SF](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-string-format/blob/master/phc-sf-spec.md) which does however look similar.

Comment: The main difference is that the PHC-SF format allows for named parameters instead of un-named position reliant parametrization.

Answer (score 3):

The `$` separate different parts of the hash string. The first part `2y` is an identifier for which algorithm was used. `10` says that the cost parameter is 10 (which means $2^{10}$ iterations for the key expansion) and after that the salt is stored. The `/` are part of the Base64 encoding of the binary data and not special characters.

`M8z/Bcli/eh3ay5.4w4Y5.` should be the encoded salt and the rest `hbTZ2wrwDKdJXkCQ7HuFazAzOqZzl4.` is your hash. (Note that the last dot is part of your hash as bcrypt saves the hash as 31 character.)

See for futher informations [PassLib documentation for Modular Crypt Format](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/modular_crypt_format.html)